# Difference between res/ and resources/

Tags: android-studio, android-resources, jetbrains-ide, android-assets

Is there a difference between `res/` and `resources/`.?? If I simply create a new directory and title it `resources`, it is not displayed as a normal directory, seems like `resources` is a keyword unlike `temp` which shows as a normal directory.

[image: AS Screenshot]

We commonly name a resource folder `res` in the lib directory to hold `drawables, values, layout, etc..`

and then in the `test` directory we put sample json and other items needed for testing in `resources`. I'm just wondering if there is actually a difference between these?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test` folder contains code (usually test code, unit tests, etc...) that runs on your local PC or laptop. The code compiled and eventually run using the installed Java on your machine the same way as pure Java projects with some minor differences. So basically the purpose of the `test` folder is to test parts of application code that don't have a dependency on the Android SDK and without using an Android device. Also on the side, there's another test folder which is `androidTest`, it also used for testing parts of the application but with using an Android device, meaning an actual test application is loaded on the device and it executes the tests which have a dependency on the Android SDK.

That being said, pure Java projects or code usually use `resources` folder and not `res` (as far I have seen while using IDEs). When compiling and then running the pure Java projects or code, the contents of the `resources` folder are placed at the root of the Java classpath so that the code being executed finds its `resources` there.

Android Studio or the Android Gradle Plugin seems to handle both differently (in terms of packaging them into the final `aar` or `apk`), so it is best that there is only `res` in `main` or `androidTest` folder and also that there is only `resources` in `test` folder.